# Mac app: want to copy system files out of the protected location, and failed

Tags: macos, file, permissions, copy

In my Mac program, I want to ***copy the file*** located in /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/xx.plist     ***to another disc***.

Presumably it will ***failed***, and it is.
I use the api of   ***copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:***  to do this,
and I NSLog out the error infomation:
it says /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/xx.plist  ***this file couldn't be opened because I don't have permission to view it.
The operation couldn't be completed, Permission denied.***

And can anyone could introduce me to some documentations or sample codes that I should read to solve my problem? Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do something that requires the user to be an administrator (or root), which requires elevated access. The way to do go about this in OSX is to factor out the privileged code into a separate executable that is run with elevated permissions, after having prompted the user for an administrator's credentials.

Take a look at OSX Authorization services for prompting the user: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html

And SMJobBless for creating the application with elevated rights: -
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html